# how to show custom map in MapBox IOS sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox

I am new in MapBox IOS sdk and i have no idea,how to load custom Map in MapBox.
Here my Custom Map:

https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/faridullah.loj1n5f3/page.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZmFyaWR1bGxhaCIsImEiOiJVU3ZCNS1VIn0.Owqu7VB5OZQbGj3LBBpPOA#16/33.6471/72.9881

and my code:

```
#define kMapboxMapID @"faridullah.loj1n5f3"

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

RMMapboxSource *onlineSource = [[RMMapboxSource alloc] initWithMapID:kMapboxMapID];

RMMapView *mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds andTilesource:onlineSource];

    mapView.zoom = 5;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;

}
```

but the markers doesnot display on device...

Comment: What is your issue exactly? The documentation has very good example code

Comment: @jalone my issue is that ,the markers doesnot display on device..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow this example and implement the needed or delegate methods

https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk/examples/marker-custom-image/

Comment: ok i understand this example,but my point here is,we cannot load our custom map, as we design in mapbox project,without programmatically in ios,just from url....?

Comment: You can't load the custom map or you cant load the markers?

Comment: ,the markers arenot displaying in my custom map,,,which i already make in custom map in web,but they are not display in ios device..

Comment: Uhmm i was not aware it was possible to design custom markers in the map editor. I either am missing something or you aren't grasping the proper way. To show the markers you need to declare and show them programmatically, and if you want custom aspect also to implement the methods needed for it.

Comment: it's means that first get data manually from MapBox,then implement programmatically in ios...